# Is it still a force at 2nd?

Tags: rules, baseball

Man on first, grounder to 1st baseman, he steps on 1st to get the runner out and throws to 2nd for the double play.  Is it a force at 2nd or does it become a tag play?

Answer (score 5):

The runner must be tagged out. To quote from the [MLB rules, Rule 5.09(b)(6)](http://mlb.mlb.com/mlb/downloads/y2016/official_baseball_rules.pdf):

> if a following runner is put out on a force play, the force is removed and the
>   runner must be tagged to be put out.

The following runner in your scenario is the batter-runner, so the force is removed as soon as the first baseman steps onto the base.